# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in

Tags: php, wordpress, implode

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
I've changed PHP version form 7.4 to 8 and got this error:

---

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-content/themes/maran/lib/utilities.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-content/themes/maran/lib/utilities.php(63): implode()
#1 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-content/themes/maran/lib/framework.php(19): require_once('/home/iranhfc/m...')
#2 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-content/themes/maran/lib/framework.php(70): PixflowFramework::Pixflow_Require_Files()
#3 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-content/themes/maran/functions.php(97): require_once('/home/iranhfc/m...')
#4 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-settings.php(525): include('/home/iranhfc/m...')
#5 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-config.php(82): require_once('/home/iranhfc/m...')
#6 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/iranhfc/m...')
#7 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/iranhfc/m...')
#8 /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/index.php(17): require('/home/iranhfc/m...')
#9 {main}
  thrown in /home/iranhfc/maransanat.com/wp-content/themes/maran/lib/utilities.php on line 63
```

---

The code:

```
if(strpos(implode(get_option('active_plugins'),' '),"bookly")>0){
    $library_to_include[]='bookly';
}
```

Comment: It was likely always an error. But now that you've upgraded, it's no longer a "warning" or "notice". ... So just debug it. The trace says the 2nd param to `implode()` must be an array. You have a string.

Comment: It's a case of you having your "separator" and "array" in the wrong parameter place. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: I find this error when it's time to re-install wp-cli.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @GetSet stated, the arguments in `implode` are the wrong way round.

```
if(strpos(implode(' ', get_option('active_plugins')),"bookly")>0){
    $library_to_include[]='bookly';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implode() function second parameter must be array.

Deprecated non array data type in second parameter. https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30797989)